# Cannot get the value of hidden weights of RNN

Tags: pytorch

I declare my RNN as

```
self.rnn = torch.nn.RNN(input_size=encoding_dim, hidden_size=1, num_layers=1, nonlinearity='relu')
```

Later

```
self.rnn.all_weights
# [[Parameter containing:
tensor([[-0.8099, -0.9543,  0.1117,  0.6221,  0.5034, -0.6766, -0.3360, -0.1700,
         -0.9361, -0.3428]], requires_grad=True), Parameter containing:
tensor([[-0.1929]], requires_grad=True), Parameter containing:
tensor([0.7881], requires_grad=True), Parameter containing:
tensor([0.4320], requires_grad=True)]]

self.rnn.all_weights[0][0][0].values
# {RuntimeError}Could not run 'aten::values' with arguments from the 'CPU' backend. 'aten::values' is only available for these backends: [SparseCPU, Autograd, Profiler, Tracer].
```

Clearly I see the value of the weights, but cannot access to it. [Documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html) says I need to specify requires_grad=True, but that does not work.

Is there a more elegant and usable way than `self.rnn.all_weights[0][0][0]?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`torch.nn.Module.named_parameters`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.named_parameters) or [`torch.nn.Module.parameters`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.parameters).

```
>>> import torch.nn as nn
>>> model = nn.RNN(input_size=encoding_dim, hidden_size=1, num_layers=1, nonlinearity='relu')
>>> weights = []
>>> for name, parameter in model.named_parameters():
...     weights.append({name: parameter[0]})
...
>>> just_weights = []
>>> for parameter in model.parameters():
...     just_weights.append(parameter[0])
...
```

Comment: That does not work. `just_weights[0].values()` gives `*** RuntimeError: Could not run 'aten::values' with arguments from the 'CPU' backend. 'aten::values' is only available for these backends: [SparseCPU, Autograd, Profiler, Tracer].`

Comment: Is there any reason why you're trying to use [`torch.Tensor.values`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.values)? It specifies in the documentation that you can only use it on certain tensors. If you want the just the numeric values, you can do `torch.tensor.data` to do that.